# How to use oAuth tokens

Tags: c#, rest, oauth

I'm using a library to get an 'oAuth_token' and 'oAuth_token_secret'.

If I make a request to a REST web service how are those two keys leveraged to verify authentication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Providing a C# example is a little difficult because there are a number of variables i.e. the signature method being used, additional parameters the service might be expecting etc. which would affect the complexity of the example.

I've developed an open source [OAuth library for .Net](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth) and posted an article on [beginning to use OAuth](http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,83488336-290d-4c4b-a314-14fe255e5b4e.aspx) that might help to get you started -  I tried to find a developers page / API specification to brightkite - but because it's a beta service I don't have access - so perhaps post me a invite to this service via my [blog](http://blog.bittercoder.com/) and I can have a go at developing an example brightkite client at which point this answer can be revisited with some concrete example code useful to others.

Comment: I sent you an invite to brightkite.  I appreciate the blog post.  Digesting it now.  I appreciate that you went the extra step that other blog posts did not.  That extra step being that you identified how to get the access token and then how to use it.